# Change individual cell forecolor on mouse enter?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Could it be possible to change the forecolor of a cell on mouse enter? I can change all the cell fore color on mouse enter but I want to change only each cell forecolor on mouse enter?

Here's how to do it:

```
Private Sub myGrid_CellMouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles myGrid.CellMouseEnter
    myGrid.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can handle [`CellMouseEnter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseenter(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`CellMouseLeave`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseleave(v=vs.110).aspx) and first check if the cell is not a header cell, then set fore color of style of cell to the desired color:

```
Private Sub myGrid_CellMouseEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles myGrid.CellMouseEnter
    If (e.ColumnIndex < 0 OrElse e.RowIndex < 0) Then Return
    Dim cell = myGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
    cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
End Sub

Private Sub myGrid_CellMouseLeave(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles myGrid.CellMouseLeave
    If (e.ColumnIndex < 0 OrElse e.RowIndex < 0) Then Return
    Dim cell = myGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
    cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, beat me to it by seconds :) All I can say is +1 and you could use `OrElse` in preference to `Or`.